# How to bound this difference between two logarithmic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

I want to bound the difference between two logarithmic expression shown below with a constant number i.e not function of $x,y,z$ where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{C}$. The difference is

$$ \log\bigl(1+(|z|+|x|+|y|)^2\bigl)-\log \bigl(1 + (|z| +\sqrt{|x|^2+|y|^2})^2\big) \leq \text{CONSTANT} $$

Any ideas is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing $|x|,|y|,|z|$ by $a,b,c$ and exponentiating, we need to show that
$$
\frac{1+(a+b+c)^2}{1+(a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2})^2} \le \text{CONSTANT}
$$
for nonnegative real numbers $a,b,c$. This is trivially true in the compact region $\{ (a,b,c)\in\Bbb R_{\ge0}^3\colon a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2} \le 1 \}$. Outside this region, we have $a+b+c \ge a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2} \ge 1$, which implies $1+(a+b+c)^2 \le 2(a+b+c)^2$; it therefore suffices to show that
$$
\frac{a+b+c}{a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}} \le \text{CONSTANT},
$$
since
$$
\frac{1+(a+b+c)^2}{1+(a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2})^2} \le \frac{2(a+b+c)^2}{(a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2})^2} = 2 \bigg( \frac{a+b+c}{a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}} \bigg)^2.
$$
But since $b+c \le 2\max\{b,c\}$ while $\sqrt{b^2+c^2} \ge \max\{b,c\}$, we see (setting $m=\max\{b,c\}$) that
$$
\frac{a+b+c}{a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}} \le \frac{a+2m}{a+m} \le \frac{2a+2m}{a+m} =2.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, can you please tell me why it trivially true in the compact region $\{ (a,b,c)\in\Bbb R_{\ge0}^3\colon a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2} \le 1 \}$.? Thanks again. @Greg Martin

Comment: Did you mean to say $\{ (a,b,c)\in\Bbb R_{\ge0}^3\colon a+b+c \leq 1 \}$. instead? Thanks.

Comment: Any continuous function is bounded in any compact region.

Comment: do you mean to say that the function i.e the difference, we are trying to bound is continuous over this trivial compact region, is it not continuos outside this region? @Greg Martin

Comment: btw can we use similar tricks to the one you presented here, do explicity find the constant under the compact region?

Comment: It is continuous everywhere. I just need to rule out that small region to perform one step in the subsequent argument. - If you're interested in the best value of the constant, then you're asking about maximizing the given function - that's a standard multivariable calculus problem.

Comment: thank you. Can you please tell me which step is violated in that compact region?

Comment: and so in general finding a constant in that region might not be possible?

Comment: Please read the answer line by line; I promise the answers to your questions are in there.

Comment: yup notcied that later thanks